# MSVC not recognizing 'direct' base class constructor of template class inheriting a template class

Tags: c++, inheritance, visual-c++

This is *not* a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer).

Below, I list my base class as well as how I am deriving a class from it:

```cpp
template<template<size_t, typename...> typename D>
struct Modifier
{
    // some static variables
};

template<typename M, size_t U, typename T, typename... S>
struct Base
{
    // some implementations
};

template<size_t U, typename T>
struct Derived;

template<>
struct Modifier<Derived>;

template<size_t U, typename T>
struct Derived : Base<Modifier<Derived>, U, T, double>
{
    using Base<Modifier<Derived>, U, T, double>::Base;
};
```

To provide some context, the idea is that the implementation of `Base` will access some static variables from `M` in order to change the behaviour of a couple of functions.

When I compile this with msvc (build tools v142), it complains about:

```
1>...: error C3210:  'Base<Modifier<Derived<2,unsigned __int64> >,2,unsigned __int64,double>': a member using-declaration can only be applied to a base class member
1>...: error C3881:  can only inherit constructor from direct base
```

Yet, when I introduce `using mod_t = Modifier<Derived>;` and apply that in the implementation of `Derived` instead of the full name, it correctly compiles.

By the way, whether I define `Derived` like above or like:

```cpp
template<size_t U, typename T>
struct Derived : Base<Modifier<Derived>, U, T, double>
{
    using parent_type = Base<Modifier<Derived>, U, T, double>;
    using parent_type::Base;
};
```

or

```cpp
template<size_t U, typename T>
struct Derived : Base<Modifier<Derived>, U, T, double>
{
    using parent_type = Base<Modifier<Derived>, U, T, double>;
    using parent_type::parent_type;
};
```

I will still get an error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: This seems like compiler bug. Clang builds it just fine. Note, that you need c++17 for template template typename parameter.

Comment: MSVC will build it as long as it doesn't get instantiated. It was my assumption too considering the silliness of the workaround. This is msvc 2019, and I use similar constructs elsewhere in my code, its only this case that gives me issues. Is this something I should submit on their bug report?

Comment: I just instatiated Derived class and clang still builds it just fine. Gcc also builds it without problems. Looks like compiler bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue (with msvc) is actually related to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56398504/template-template-member-inheritance-with-using):

> Simpler work-around to avoid injected-class-name is to use full name.

In the above, `Derived` needs to be prefixed as `::Derived` and this will then successfully compile.